# .htaccess is adding extra 'C:/xampp/htdocs/' to redirect url on xampp/localhost- how to remove?

Tags: .htaccess, xampp

I'm trying to use an `.htaccess` file to redirect requests for `http://example.org/folder/folder/index.php?with=parameters`,
to `http://example.org/index.php?with=parameters` - removing the `folder/folder/` part from the request url.

To test my `.htaccess` file, I've created an `example` folder in my `C:\xampp\htdocs` folder, with an `index.php` file that just echos the request url and an `.htaccess` file that looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^folder/folder/index\.php(.*) index.php$1 [R=301,L]
```

If I now go to `http://localhost/example/folder/folder/index.php?with=parameters`
it redirects to the url `http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/example/index.php?with=parameters` which doesn't exist (forbidden).

So it is removing the `folder/folder/` part, but it is adding `C:/xampp/htdocs/` to the url.

How can I get rid of the extra `C:/xampp/htdocs/` in the new url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^folder/folder/index\.php(.*) index.php$1 [R=301,L]
> ```
>
> If I now go to `http://localhost/example/folder/folder/index.php?with=parameters` it redirects to the url `http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/example/index.php?with=parameters` which doesn't exist (forbidden).

This is because of the *relative* substitution string (`index.php$1`) - second argument to the `RewriteRule` directive. It is *relative* because it does not start with a slash (root-relative, eg. `/index.php`) or does not start with a scheme+hostname (absolute, eg.. `https://example.com/...`). In `.htaccess`, a *relative* substitution string is treated as a file-path (not a URL-path) and so the *directory-prefix* (ie. `C:/xampp/htdocs/` in this case) is added back at the end of the rewriting process (necessary for internal rewrites) - which is exposed when triggering the external redirect.

You basically just need a slash prefix on the *substitution* string to make it root-relative. But because you are also in the `/example` subdirectory, this also needs to be included. eg. `/example/index.php`. (There are various ways to "capture" the `example` subdirectory if reqd, to prevent it being hardcoded.)

In addition, you don't need to do anything with regards to the query string (URL parameters). These are passed through to the substitution by default. But, importantly, the `RewriteRule` *pattern* only matches against the URL-path anyway, not the query string, so your capturing subpattern (ie. `(.*)`) at the end of the *pattern* is not actually doing anything anyway.

So, all you need is the following:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/folder/index\.php$ /example/index.php [R=301,L]
```

Note the addition of the slash prefix (and `/example` subdirectory) on the *substitution* string. The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against a relative URL-path (relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file - so the `example` directory should not be specified here.)

The query string on the original request is passed through to the *substitution* string by default. Only if you are wanting to *change* the query string (URL params) in some way would you need to do anything.

Note that you will need to clear your browser (and possibly any intermediary) cache(s) since the erroneous 301 (permanent) redirect will have been cached persistently by the browser. You should test with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid these caching issues.

---

#### A note on `RewriteBase`

Alternatively, you could use the `RewriteBase` directive. The `RewriteBase` directive specifies the URL-path that should be prefixed to relative substitution strings (this overrides the *directory-prefix*). For example, the following is equivalent<sup>***1**</sup> to the above (in this limited example):

```
RewriteBase /example

RewriteRule ^folder/folder/index\.php$ index.php [R=301,L]
```

Note that the `RewriteBase` directive affects the entire file and can only occur once in the file. (The value to the `RewriteBase` directive does not need to include a trailing slash - it is optional, but is always implied. The docs are not consistent in this respect.)

However, generally, when issuing external redirects I would not rely on the `RewriteBase`. Using an explicit root-relative (or absolute) *substitution* string in the rule itself is recommended.

<sup>***1**</sup> It's not directly equivalent, since the `RewriteBase` is only applied at the end of the rewriting process, not as the `RewriteRule` directive is processed. But the result is the same in most cases.

Comment: UPDATE: I've added the `/example` subdirectory to the rule, since `index.php` is not in the root!